# Is it possible to store an instance of a Countdown Timer inside a Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am just curious if a Countdown Timer can be stored in a room database. The reason is if the app crashes or closes, it can re-instantiate the timer and continue where it left off. I also would like to remove the instance when the time runs out. I figured I could do that with a query in the DAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.

However, you don't need to save the `CountDownTimer` — you need to save the time when it will be done. You know that when you create the `CountDownTimer`, as you can find out the current time (`System.currentTimeMillis()` or `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`) and you know how long you are setting the timer for. So, save the ending time. If you need to recreate the `CountDownTimer`, you can calculate the new duration based on the current time and the saved ending time.